# List contents of row in a table - but only once

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table where one field contains a free to choose text. Some of these texts are identical, some are not. So as an example, this may look like this:

```
Joe
Jim
Jack
Jack
Jim
Jack
Jane
```

Now I want to list all the contents of these fields, but compared on a content level so that every data is shown only once. Means the result from my data have to look like this:

```
Joe
Jim
Jack
Jane
```

The double-entries Jim and Jack are shown only once although they are contained more often.

My question: is there a SQL-statement which covers this or do I have to filter these data in the result?

Thanks!

Comment: Try a search for the MySQL command `GROUP BY`.

Comment: sql has a keyword called `distinct.`

Comment: You can use `DISTINCT`, i.e: `SELECT DISTINCT column1, column2, ...
FROM table_name;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select distinct fieldname from your_table_name
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT DISTINCT nameField
FROM YourTable
```